# Single value list index into integer in Python?

Tags: python, list, indexing, integer

Is it possible to turn a single value list (e.g. [5]) index (e.g. 4) into an integer when enumerating it? I'm trying to make a program that creates a random username with given words and numbers, and I want to delete a word if it has already been used before:

```
import random

# data (words/numbers)
words = ['Cool', 'Boring', 'Tall', 'Short']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

# words
word_1 = random.choice(words)
selected_word = [i for i,x in enumerate(words) if x == word_1]
words.pop(selected_word)
word_2 = random.choice(words)

# numbers
number_1 = random.choice(numbers)
number_2 = random.choice(numbers)

# printing username
print(word_1+word_2+number_1+number_2)
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? If you have a single-value list `lst=[5]`, and you index it with `lst[4]`, that's going to be an `IndexError`, because there aren't that many values.

Comment: Or are you just asking how to turn a string into an int, so in `for number in numbers:`, you can do something with `4`, `5`, etc. instead of `'4'`, `'5'`, etc.? If so, you just use `int(number)` in the code inside the loop instead of `number`.

Comment: FWIW, deleting stuff from the middle of a list isn't very efficient, so it's generally better to use different logic when you have a choice. Also, what happens if you want to create more than one username? I recommend abarnert's approach: use `sample`. And I'd probably use `randrange` to generate a 2 digit number, and then convert that to a string, rather than choosing from a list of digit strings.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code… I'm not sure what it's supposed to be doing, but I can make some guesses.

First you pick a random word. Then you look up the indices of all words that match that word. Then you want to use that list of indices with `pop`.

Well, you *can* fix that:

```
for idx in reversed(selected_word):
    words.pop(idx)
```

(The `reversed` is important so you pop the rightmost ones first.)

But there's no need for that, because there should only ever be one copy of `word_1` in `words`, and therefore only one index in `selected_word`. So you can just do this:

```
words.pop(selected_word[0])
```

But in that case, the comprehension is unnecessary. Getting all matches and taking the first does the same thing as taking the first match, and lists already have a method for that: `index`.

```
words.pop(words.index(word_1))
```

But really, instead of picking a word and then looking it up to get the index, you could just get the index:

```
index = random.randrange(len(words))
word_1 = words.pop(index)
```

Or, most simply of all, just replace the whole thing with:

```
word_1, word_2 = random.sample(words, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you wanted this (without deleting any word)?:

```
>>> import random
>>> words = ['Cool', 'Boring', 'Tall', 'Short']
>>> numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> selected_word_indices = set()
>>> def select_word():
        if len(selected_word_indices) == len(words):
            raise Exception("No More Unique Word Left")
        while True:
            chosen_index = random.randint(0,len(words)-1)
            if chosen_index not in selected_word_indices:
                chosen = words[chosen_index]
                selected_word_indices.add(chosen_index)
                return chosen

>>> word_1 = select_word()
>>> word_2 = select_word()

>>> number_1 = random.choice(numbers)
>>> number_2 = random.choice(numbers)

>>> print(word_1+word_2+number_1+number_2)
```

With `del` selecting will be simpler but a copy of `words` will be required (if you want the original list, `words` unchanged):

```
>>> words_copy = words.copy()
>>> def select_word():
        if len(words_copy) == 0:
            raise Exception("No More Unique Word Left")
        chosen_index = random.randint(0,len(words_copy)-1)
        chosen_word = words_copy[chosen_index]
        del words_copy[chosen_index]
        return chosen_word
```